# firebase.database is not a function error - html page

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to figure out how to connect firebase to a HTML page, but I keep getting an error saying firebase.database isn't a function.
I have already looked a lot of solutions for this, but most of them aren't applicable.

I have already tried changing  `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase.js"></script>`

I have also tried importing firebase with `import` commands instead of using src links as per this solution: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1265, but it failed to find the packages.

Heres the applicable code:

```
   <div>
        <h1>Firebase web app</h1>
        <button id="submitBtn" onclick="submitClick()">click here</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

    <script>

        //Stats hidden for privacy, but I got this from a copy paste from my firebase SDK config snippet
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: (key),
            authDomain: (domain),
            databaseURL: (URL),
            projectId: (id),
            storageBucket: (storageBucket),
            messagingSenderId: (senderId),
            appId: (appId)
         };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        function submitClick() {
            var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

            firebaseRef.child("Text").set("some Value");
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not importing the `firebase-database.js` SDK, which is what defines `firebase.database()`.

To fix it, add:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

In general: you should include only the SDKs you actually use. So with your current code, that'd just be `firebase-app` and `firebase-database`.